# SQL Total Distinct Count on Group By Query

Tags: sql, group-by, count, amazon-redshift, distinct

Trying to get an overall distinct count of the employees for a range of records which has a group by on it.

I've tried using the "over()" clause but couldn't get that to work. Best to explain using an example so please see my script below and wanted result below.

**EDIT:**
I should mention I'm hoping for a solution that does not use a sub-query based on my "sales_detail" table below because in my real example, the "sales_detail" table is a very complex sub-query.

Here's the result I want. Column "wanted_result" should be 9:

[image]

Sample script:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [sales_detail] (
    [employee] varchar(100),[customer] varchar(100),[startdate] varchar(100),[enddate] varchar(100),[saleday] int,[timeframe] varchar(100),[saleqty] numeric(18,4)
);

INSERT INTO [sales_detail]
    ([employee],[customer],[startdate],[enddate],[saleday],[timeframe],[saleqty])
VALUES
    ('Wendy','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','5','Afternoon','1'),
    ('Wendy','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','5','Morning','5'),
    ('Wendy','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','6','Morning','6'),
    ('Dexter','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','2','Mid','2.5'),
    ('Jennifer','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','4','Morning','2.75'),
    ('Lila','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','2','Morning','3.75'),
    ('Rita','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','2','Mid','1'),
    ('Tony','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','4','Mid','2'),
    ('Tony','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','1','Morning','6'),
    ('Mike','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','4','Mid','1.5'),
    ('Logan','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','3','Morning','6.25'),
    ('Blake','Chris','8/1/2019','8/12/2019','4','Afternoon','0.5')
;

  SELECT
    [timeframe],
    SUM([saleqty]) AS [total_qty],
    COUNT(DISTINCT [s].[employee]) AS [employee_count1],
    SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT [s].[employee])) OVER() AS [employee_count2],
    9 AS [wanted_result]
  FROM (
    SELECT 
        [employee],[customer],[startdate],[enddate],[saleday],[timeframe],[saleqty]
    FROM 
        [sales_detail]
  ) AS [s]
  GROUP BY
    [timeframe]
;
```

Comment: You tagged postgresql but the syntax seems like SQL Server.

Comment: This is Redshift which is based off of Postgresql

Comment: I have never seen `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option-

```
SELECT
[timeframe],
SUM([saleqty]) AS [total_qty],
COUNT(DISTINCT [s].[employee]) AS [employee_count1],
SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT [s].[employee])) OVER() AS [employee_count2],
[wanted_result]
-- select count form sub query
FROM (
    SELECT 
    [employee],[customer],[startdate],[enddate],[saleday],[timeframe],[saleqty],
    (select COUNT(DISTINCT [employee]) from [sales_detail]) AS [wanted_result]
    --caculate the count with first sub query
    FROM [sales_detail]
) AS [s]
GROUP BY
[timeframe],[wanted_result]
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I'd rather a solution that doesn't use a sub-query on my "sales_detail" table because in my real project it's a complex sub-query not a simple table. I just did this for demonstration.

Comment: if you use GROUP BY, either you need to JOIN a Query result or use Sub Query to get an aggregated results from overall data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are simply looking for a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for all employees in the table? I believe this query will return the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  [timeframe],
  SUM([saleqty]) AS [total_qty],
  COUNT(DISTINCT [s].[employee]) AS [employee_count1],
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [employee]) FROM [sales_detail]) AS [employee_count2],
  9 AS [wanted_result]
FROM #sales_detail [s]
GROUP BY
  [timeframe]
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I'd rather a solution that doesn't use a sub-query on my "sales_detail" table because in my real project it's a complex sub-query not a simple table. I just did this for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trick where you only count each person on the first day they are seen:

```
select timeframe, sum(saleqty) as total_qty),
       count(distinct employee) as employee_count1,
       sum( (seqnum = 1)::int ) as employee_count2
       9 as wanted_result
from (select sd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee order by startdate) as seqnum
      from sales_detail sd
     ) sd
group by timeframe;
```

Note:  From the perspective of performance, your complex subquery is only evaluated once.